# Pyzmq SUB doesn't receive messages unless I use bind

Tags: sockets, zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq, low-latency

I have 3 processes, let's call them `host` and `worker1` and `worker2`. I want `worker1` and `worker2` to be able to communicate with each other directly via PUB/SUB sockets (with `host` interjecting intermittently), so I have the following setup:

```py
# host
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind('ipc:///tmp/comms')

# worker1
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect('ipc:///tmp/comms')
socket.send(b'worker1')

# worker2
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('ipc:///tmp/comms')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'worker1')
socket.recv()
```

As of now, this setup doesn't work. `worker1` sends fine, but `worker2` never seems to receive the message. However, if I now change the setup to this:

```py
# host
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect('ipc:///tmp/comms')

# worker1
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect('ipc:///tmp/comms')
socket.connect(b'worker1')

# worker2
socket = ctx.Socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.bind('ipc:///tmp/comms')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'worker1')
socket.recv()
```

It works just fine. However, if I also bind in `host`, it stops working again.

Why is this? What happens if I now have `workerN` which also needs to subscribe to `worker1`, how can I bind from all the processes? What are these bind/connect semantics? Isn't `host`, being the long-lived process, doing the right thing by `bind`ing, and if so, why is `worker2` failing to receive when it is `connect`ing?

---

MWE: https://gist.github.com/ooblahman/f8f9724b9995b9646ebdb79d26afd68a

```
import zmq
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

addr = 'ipc:///tmp/test_zmq'

def worker1():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    sock.connect(addr)
    while True:
        sock.send(b'worker1')
        print('worker1 sent')
        time.sleep(1)

def worker2():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.connect(addr) # Change this to bind
    sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'worker1')
    while True:
        sock.recv()
        print('worker2 heard')

def main():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    sock.bind(addr) # Change this to connect (or remove entirely)

    p1 = Process(target=worker1)
    p2 = Process(target=worker2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Isn't `host`, being the long-lived process, doing the right thing by `bind`ing,...?"*

Well, ***no one can tell***.
There is no supporting evidence for any such claim ( *"**being** the long-lived process"* ), the less for any such deducted assumption ( *"<sub>... and if so,</sub> **why** is `worker2` failing to receive when it is connecting?"* )

What we ***can tell*** is,
that `worker2` may try to use either of the methods, be it a `{ .bind() | .connect() }`, successfully, yet still gets no warranty ever *( a wonderful Zen-of-Zero )* whether it will or will not `POSACK` on receive. That depends on many other factors, the more in [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) systems:

- if / when / how was the `TOPIC`-list managed ( using and the order of call(s) to the `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ... )` method ),
- if `PUB`-side agents did ever send any such message that was actually matching to any topic actively subscribed to or not,
- if default and / or configured resources were actually all in a state, which was sufficient for accepting any such potentially deliverable message for a transport on a `.send()`-er side, having all necessary means of transport from sender-side `Context()`-instance to the hands of the intended receiving-side `Context()`-instance and, finally, for a local delivery thereof via a `.recv()`-method on any intended receiver-side(s) or not,
  so indeed not easy to say in general. Your code suffers from several principal collisions:

The `worker1`, in a **`PUB`**-side role will actually never deliver a bit in the first example above.

---

> **Q** : *"Why is this?"*

Asking a `PUB` to setup a transport-link towards another `PUB` is not a legitimate ZeroMQ Formal Communication Archetype pattern - such a call to `.connect()`-method, responsible for asking for such a setup, ought get inspected for returning an error and the rest of the story is like observing two people, a `PUB`-in-`host` and a `PUB`-in-`worker1`, both trying to shout as much a each can into to their microphone, yet no one ever listening to a speaker, so never hearing a bit from anyone else.

Doable, yet not functional, is it?

---

> **Q** : *"What happens if I now have `workerN` which also needs to subscribe to `worker1`, how can I bind from all the processes?"*

We need not `.bind()`, unless we want to.

If `workerN` wants to subscribe to `worker1`, it may `.bind()`, yet `worker1` has no clue there has appeared any new `workerN` ( to which it might want to `.connect()` ), does it? So the `.connect()` is often let for the dynamically changing `SUB`-side N-ary cohort of the `1:N`-setup ( actually being `M:N`, in principle ) - having the `PUB`-side on a known transport-class(es ... yes, can have more than one AccessPoints using more than one, ... yes, multiple transport-classes - all may get used from the one and the very same `PUB`-agent for communication with one or many remote `SUB`-agents - isn't that cool? ) - as the `.bind()`-(s) established a know point of access for the dynamic cohort of **`N`**-agents trying to `.connect()` at some unknown time in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I see the error you pointed out with Pub/Pub communications. I ended up fixing this by using XPUB/XSUB on the `host` process to do the many-to-many communication.